# Need help to put gear shifter back together!

Tags: shimano, gears

My daughter has Shimano SL TX30 gears on her bike....I think they might be Tourney, from searches I've done. The gears on the right handlebar has a button to go down gears. I stupidly took it off the bike and opened it, with plans of changing the cable. Well couple bits of plastic popped out and I don't know how they go back in to be able to change gears with it. If you use either the lever or the button for changing gears it would make a clicking sound. I'm hoping someone might have a pic of the inside so I know where and how the pieces go back in.
Searched the Internet with no luck as yet.

Thanks in advance xox

Comment: I did the same once - it was easier to buy a replacement shifter because these shifters are not designed to be serviced.  On the plus side, tourney is the lowest grade and not an expensive racing part so it shouldn't be too costly.

Comment: Generally speaking there's a round plug/bung to undo, and then the inner cable can be pushed through.  Only do this in the lowest (slackest wire tension) gear.

Comment: Rule #1 for index shifters is not to take them apart.  Everyone learns this lesson the hard way :)

Comment: Consider it a Japanese puzzle, to play with when you have nothing else to do.You might find an exploded view on Shimano's website. But for the sake of sanity it's better to buy a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at Shimano Technical Docs there are these pages:

https://si.shimano.com/#/en/search/Keyword?name=sl%20tx30

https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/ev/EV-SL-TX30-2493.pdf

whether there's enough detail in that exploded image I don't know!

Is it the left or right hand shifter?
If its the right hand one , I have one you could have cheap (I'm in the UK)

Cheers